# Retrieving extra columns from another table with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to select some entities from the database with their translation in a specific language

This is my database schema
[image: ER Diagram]

This is the query I'm trying to produce

```
SELECT identifier,
       (SELECT tv.value FROM translations_values AS tv WHERE tv.language = :lang AND tv.key = title) AS title_translated,
       (SELECT tv.value FROM translations_values AS tv WHERE tv.language = :lang AND tv.key = content) AS content_translated
  FROM posts
```

This is my mapped entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(title = "posts")
@NamedQuery(title = "Post.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Post i")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(title = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer identifier;

    @Column(title = "title", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer titleIdentifier;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(title = "title")
    public TranslationKey title;

    @Formula(value = "(SELECT tv.value FROM translations_values AS tv WHERE tv.language = {lang} AND tv.key = title)")
    public String titleTranslated;

    @Column(title = "content", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer contentIdentifier;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(title = "content")
    private TranslationKey content;
    
    @Formula(value = "(SELECT tv.value FROM translations_values AS tv WHERE tv.language = {lang} AND tv.key = content)")
    public String contentTranslated;

    // Getter & Setter

}
```

The last step of this procedure is a Hibernate `Interceptor` which replaces `{lang}` with the requested language id. The `@Formula` allows me to create where conditions so that I can search for posts by title and content also in the repository I can create methods like "findByTitleContaining" and hibernate automatically creates the correct where conditions.

My question is is there a better way to do this thing? I tried to fetch the translations in EAGER mode but I ran into the SELECT N+1 problem

Answer (score 0):

Just write a HQL query for this and remove the formula mappings from your entity.

```
SELECT p.identifier,
       (SELECT tv.value FROM TranslationsValue AS tv WHERE tv.language = :lang AND tv.key = p.title),
       (SELECT tv.value FROM TranslationsValue AS tv WHERE tv.language = :lang AND tv.key = p.content)
FROM Post p
```

The result will be an `Object[]` with the identifier at position 0 and the translated data on position 1 and 2.